# How is the magic link generated in NextAuth email provider?

Tags: node.js, next.js, nodemailer, next-auth

When creating a NextAuth sign-in, how is the URL generated because I need to make it https and create. certificate for it. My NextAuth config looks like this:

```
import EmailProvider from "next-auth/providers/email";
...
providers: [
  EmailProvider({
    server: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER,
    from: process.env.EMAIL_FROM,
    sendVerificationRequest({
      identifier: email,
      url,
      provider: { server, from },
    }) {
      /* your function */
    },
  }),
]
```

Where is the url coming from in `sendVerificationRequest`? I thought it was `NEXTAUTH_URL` but it's different. Thanks for any help.